# Coinflip animation not spinning correctly (and multiple transforms in css animation)

Tags: html, css, animation

Alright, so I have two problems, the first problem is that I want the animation to rotate over the X-axes, but it looks weird, because it's not spinning inside each other, [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2j24812/)

Then my other problem is, when I add something like `scale(1.5)` to the transform animation, it just seems to ignore the `rotation`, it just won't work anymore.

**HTML**

```
<div class="coin-wrapper">
  <div class="animate coin">
    <div class="terrorist"></div>
    <div class="counter-terrorist"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.animate{
  animation: rotate 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from { 
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); 
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0); 
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }

  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2160deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotateX(2160deg); 
    transform: rotateX(2160deg); 
   }
}

.coin-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
}

.coin {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.coin .counter-terrorist, .coin .terrorist {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.coin .terrorist {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image:url('https://csgoloto.com/template/img/terrorist.png');
  background-size:cover;
}

.coin .counter-terrorist {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image:url('https://csgoloto.com/template/img/counter-terrorist.png');
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the `.coin` element is being calculated as 0, so that's where the `transform-origin` is. If you make the coin fill its parent, then it looks good. You can work around the scaling problem by applying `scale` to the wrapper instead of the coin.

```css
.animate{
  animation: rotate 5s;
}
.coin-wrapper {
  animation: scale 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from { 
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); 
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0); 
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }

  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2160deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotateX(2160deg); 
    transform: rotateX(2160deg); 
   }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scale {
  from { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  to { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5); 
   }
}

.coin-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
}

.coin {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.coin .counter-terrorist, .coin .terrorist {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.coin .terrorist {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image:url('https://csgoloto.com/template/img/terrorist.png');
  background-size:cover;
}

.coin .counter-terrorist {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image:url('https://csgoloto.com/template/img/counter-terrorist.png');
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="coin-wrapper">
  <div class="animate coin">
    <div class="terrorist"></div>
    <div class="counter-terrorist"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```